# htmlspecialchars function mixed with parameter binding/statement preparing is resulting in /r and /n showing

Tags: php, mysqli

In a project I am working on for PHP and Mysqli, I have to use prepare and bind_param to for my mysqli statements. I wrote these statements before doing so and they work fine. This is before binding and preparing.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (commentid, userid, comment, commentdate) 
    VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION["userid"]."', '" . htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES) . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
      $conn->query($sql);
```

In the textarea where I write a comment, if I use enter and move to next line, the output would be something like:
Old Line New Line

Now, when I start binding values and preparing the statement my output gets a bit strange. Here is the code for that:

```
 $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (commentid, userid, comment, commentdate) 
    VALUES (NULL, ?,?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $userid, htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES));
    $stmt->execute();
```

For some reason after doing it this way if I created a new line within the text are the output would be as follows: 
Old Line/r/nNew Line

Is there something I am doing wrong that I can fix so that /r/n is not outputted to the page? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You mean `\n\r` right?

Comment: Old Line\r\nNew line I just tested it to make sure I can add a screenshot if necessary

Comment: Also if I do """" Now it would be something like \"\"\"\"\" as the output

Comment: Sounds like 2 issues, addslashes is enabled plus your outputting the line in single quotes: https://3v4l.org/86TpC

Comment: How can I disable add slashes because to me it does not look like I am outputting in single quotes! Thanks for your answers I am still fairly new to PHP

Comment: Your need to check there on http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc if they are turn them off else you need to go through all your super globals and use stripslashes. Please show all the code that outputs, else it impossible to know for sure why `\n\r` are not working.. also dont expect new lines if your outputting to the browser they don't magically turn into `<br>` tags

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem I found had nothing to do with the html special characters within the bind param. It was the fact that I was already using mysqli_real_escape_string to retrieve the comment. If you already have escaped your string then there is no need to bind it but also you can just bind it without escaping! Either works.

Answer (score -1):

Those line breaks entered into the textarea input field are converted by the `htmlspecialchars()` function into `\r\n`.

First, to remove the `\r\n`, you can use str_replace()

```
$escape_comment     = htmlspecialchars( $comment, ENT_QUOTES );
$remove_line_breaks = str_replace( "\\r\\n", '', $escape_comment );
```

Or, instead of using htmlspecialchars(), why not use strip_tags(), then you can decide which tags are allowed in comments. **Note:**Unless you know that the comment content will be formatted properly, you may not want to use `strip_tags()`

```
$escape_comment = strip_tags ( $comment, '<a><p><i><strong><li>' );
```

Comment: I think if I would not want to use strip tags because I am supposed to have no way for any html to be output on my page. I think htmlspecialchars will handle that for me. Also I am not entirely understanding your code for the preg_replace. Another thing is why wouldn't the same thing be happening with the first example I showed?

Comment: Using htmlspecailchars() will display html elements on your page, unless if you take care of it. The preg_replace() - note that `\r\n` are meta characters, they will match linebreaks, but since it has been converted to a string by the `htmlspecialchars` function, I escaped `\r\n`. Also, `\` in regex is a meta character,  I must escape it before usage else it would mean something entirely different.

Comment: htmlspecialchars does not effect new lines nor does it convert them, and strip_tags does not protect against XSS, unless you remove everything.https://3v4l.org/f8VI4

Comment: strip_tag() is even by far the best to handle XSS. It will remove all html tags from your text, isn't that what you wanted at first?

Comment: no htmlentities is for stopping XSS, strip_tags is not, strip tags is for what it says stripping tags, think ive just proven that in the link: here's another https://3v4l.org/qr79n

Comment: Really? Well, to cut this debate short, consider this code: `$str = 'my hidden script: <script>alert(0);</script>';
// echo strip_tags( $str );` And who said strip_tags() cannot be used to stop XSS.
echo htmlspecialchars( $str, ENT_QUOTES );

Comment: There is plenty of documentation out there to support that strip tags is not adequate and also may remove desired content.  htmlspecialchars is the better choice.

Comment: If for the removing of desired content, I will agree to a bit, but I digress, that is only when the HTML tags are not closed properly. And even if there are a lot of articles saying this, that doesn't make it right when you know the expected input.